# How much could you increase lift using ailerons alone?

Tags: lift, ailerons, pitch

If a plane had ailerons that could be moved in the same direction, could the lift be increased by a non-negligible amount?

Comment: Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/65300/do-ailerons-on-opposite-wings-move-together

Comment: Well, that is pretty much what flaps do, so...

Comment: @MichaelHall … that's how [flaperons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flaperon) came to be.

Comment: Related: [What is the purpose of aileron droop used in some commercial airliners?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/42221/what-is-the-purpose-of-aileron-droop-used-in-some-commercial-airliners)